# How do I add two Flickity addons at the same time?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, slider, es6-modules, flickity

I've been using [Flickity Background Lazyload](https://github.com/metafizzy/flickity-bg-lazyload) to add lazyloading functionality to my sliders, and now would like to use [Flickity asNavFor](https://github.com/metafizzy/flickity-as-nav-for) as well. Normally, I would import Flickity from the library directly (instead of from the Flickity library), like this:

```js
import Flickity from 'flickity-bg-lazyload'

const flkty = new Flickity('.element', {
    "prevNextButtons": false,
    "adaptiveHeight": true
})
```

My problem now, is I have to do the same with asNavFor. At the moment it seems to be working with asNavFor added as an extra library, sort of like a CDN, but not directly imported in the file where I need it, but I would rather import both variants of Flickity together and use it in the file.

Is this possible?

Comment: I do not know the Flickty library but you should simply be able to instantiate another object of the same class: `const flktyNav = new Flickity('controller-selector', { asNavFor: 'controlled-element-selector' })`;

Comment: I would like to have it in the same variable. Pretty much this:
`import Flickity from 'flickity-bg-lazyload';
import Flickity from 'flickity-as-nav-for';

const flkty = new Flickity('.element', {
    "prevNextButtons": false,
    "adaptiveHeight": true
});`

Comment: Have you checked the Flickity documentation at https://flickity.metafizzy.co/options.html#asnavfor and https://flickity.metafizzy.co/extras.html#module-loaders? I think it covers your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment from [secan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14201528/secan) definitely helped. Since I can't mark the comment as the answer, I'll answer it myself, for future reference.

> Have you checked the Flickity documentation at
> flickity.metafizzy.co/options.html#asnavfor and
> flickity.metafizzy.co/extras.html#module-loaders? I think it covers
> your case.

The solution is as follows:

```
import Flickity from 'flickity'
import 'flickity-bg-lazyload'
import 'flickity-as-nav-for'

const flkty = new Flickity('.element', {
    "prevNextButtons": false,
    "adaptiveHeight": true,
    "asNavFor": ".other_carousel"
})
```